In selenium java: cannot switch to modal role="dialog" displayed on page
I am opening the page here:
page
I am unable to click the cookie dialog!
I cannot see an iframe or an alert window, either. I tried getWindowHandles without success.
This is my Selenium Test:
package org.leder;


import dev.failsafe.internal.util.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.bidi.browsingcontext.BrowsingContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainTest {

    public static final String ALDI_ONLINESHOP_GUTES_FÜR_ALLE = "ALDI ONLINESHOP - Gutes für alle";

    @Test
    public void loginLogoutTest() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));

        driver.get("https://aldi-onlineshop.de");

        String title = driver.getTitle();

        System.out.println(title);

        Assert.isTrue(title.equals(ALDI_ONLINESHOP_GUTES_FÜR_ALLE), "Title is valid");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("data-testid='uc-default-wall'")));


        String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();

        Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();


        // Now iterate using Iterator
        Iterator<String> I1 = s.iterator();

        driver.switchTo().window(I1.next());


        WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("data-testid='uc-accept-all-button'"));


        submitButton.click();

        //switch to the parent window
        driver.switchTo().window(parent);

        WebElement loginMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-attr-value='My Account']"));

        loginMenu.click();



        driver.quit();
    }
}

I am expecting the modal dialog to be selected and the button to be pressed. I get an error on the css value of the modal dialog:
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: {"status":32,"value":"An invalid or illegal selector was specified"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.122)
Build info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.6.26-1-MANJARO', java.version: '17.0.10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [4ffbffb982d379cb84581e3add5c448d, findElement {value=data-testid='uc-default-wall', using=css selector}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 123.0.6312.122, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 123.0.6312.122 (31f8248cdd9..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:40857}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:40857/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.122, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 4ffbffb982d379cb84581e3add5c448d


and this
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
gives this
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

The issue is that two of your CSS selectors are not valid. That's the reason for the error, e.g.
data-testid='uc-default-wall'
data-testid='uc-accept-all-button'

should be bracketed, e.g.
[data-testid='uc-default-wall']
[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']

Your last CSS selector is valid syntax.

Suggestions...

Don't name your variables after what they contain, e.g.
public static final String ALDI_ONLINESHOP_GUTES_FÜR_ALLE = "ALDI ONLINESHOP - Gutes für alle";

Instead name it after what it represents, the home page title, e.g.
public static final String HOME_PAGE_TITLE = "ALDI ONLINESHOP - Gutes für alle";


Don't use Assert.isTrue() to check if two values are true. It's intended to check a boolean, e.g.
boolean isTrue = true;
Assert.assertTrue(isTrue, "It's true");

When comparing two values, as in this case comparing two strings, instead use Assert.assertEquals(), e.g.
Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), home_page_title, "Title is valid");

That way if the page title changes, you will get a message like
Title is valid expected [ALDI ONLINESHOP - The old title] but found [ALDI ONLINESHOP - Gutes für alle]

instead of
Title is valid expected [true] but found [false]

which is not useful.



Thank you! I bracketed the CSS selectors. On the page I still get unable to locate element for the two CSS selectors. How come?

The core of that page is inside a shadow-root. Selenium treats it like an IFRAME of sorts. See this for more info.

Please elaborate: What is the CSS selector of the shadow host? I cannot select the container with the CSS selector "[data-testid='uc-buttons-container']" or the container with the CSS selector "#uc-center-container"

It's the element directly above the #shadow-root, so <div id="usercentrics-root" data-created-at="1715608050251" style=""> which has an ID so, By.id("usercentrics-root").
